# Why angular routing adds hashtag # to the url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

***Version Used***

Angular version : 7.10
@angular/router": "~7.2.0",

***The question is***

Why angular adds a hashTag to the url.

***Example case:***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'aktion',
    component: AktionComponent
  }
```

does match the url

```
http://localhost:4200/aktion
```

but does not match the url

```
http://localhost:4200/#/aktion
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In app module, do like this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  // other imports
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) //make it false
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `PathLocationStrategy` then the server should be configured to send the `error page` also as `index.html` since normally this would result in a `404` and Angular should parse the route.

To avoid the hassle, the `HashLocationStrategy` may be used, since any part after # is ignored by the server and is only parsed from the browser. Hence you have the #.
To remove it you can update the `RouterModule configuration` as shown by the other answers.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: false }),
```

Comment: it's false by default : `RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have add this line to App Module then it adds #

```
   RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true }),
```